# Where is Capistrano retrieving the IP Address from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano3

I have to deploy a rails app after the server had a problem, and the IP Address has changed.

I've updated the IP Address in deploy/production.rb, and also git's remote branches, to the correct value, namely 192.168.30.24, but as you can see from the following output, the deployment is failing due to trying to connect over 192.168.30.23.

Where is Capistrano retrieving 192.168.30.23 from?

```
INFO [fa83a838] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update as code@192.168.30.24
DEBUG [fa83a838] Command: cd /var/www/paperless_office/repo && ( export RBENV_ROOT="~/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.0" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/paperless_office/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git remote update )
DEBUG [fa83a838]    Fetching origin
DEBUG [fa83a838]    ssh: connect to host 192.168.30.23 port 22: No route to host
```

Capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

production.rb as follows:

```
role :app, %w{192.168.30.24}
role :web, %w{192.168.30.24}
role :db,  %w{192.168.30.24}

server '192.168.30.24', user: 'code', roles: %w{web app}

after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
```

Thanks

Comment: try to add you capistrano files; it sure would help people to solve your issue

Comment: added Capfile and production.rb, didn't think they were necessary as Capfile doesn't detail the IP Address, and production.rb confirms the IP Address correction previously mentioned :)

Comment: looks like there's nothing wrong… the only thing i can see, would be that you're not passing correctly the environment. Do you have a staging.rb maybe ? is there's one, maybe rebuild the capistrano related in the bin directory… still i don't see how it would fail

Comment: The command I use: cap production deploy; so it shouldn't be picking up any other environments, the only other is staging, and thats set to deploy to a vagrant vm, with nothing in there relates to 192.168.30.23

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by removing the remote repo that Capistrano builds, so that on the next deploy, it was rebuilt using the correct IP Address.

I was deploying to /var/www/app_name so the repo to remove was /var/www/app_name/repo